# Jboss not starting - without error

Tags: jboss

I'm trying to install a fresh version of Jboss, so I Downloaded it, unzip it, and tried to launch the standalone.bat

I checked for my system environment variables, and all of them are correct.

```
Calling "G:\Download\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.co
nf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: G:\Download\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.se
rver.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.c
onfig=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
13:20:57,794 INFOS [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:20:57,909 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:20:57,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" sta
rting
```

**And that's it, nothing else, it just freeze right here. Sometimes, (1 try of 10), there is more informations like :**

```
13:28:00,821 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:28:00,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management se
rvice using socket-binding (management-http)
13:28:00,834 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:28:00,860 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
13:28:00,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log han
dlers
13:28:00,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26)
JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
13:28:00,940 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408:
 Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
13:28:00,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerServic
e Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Dr
iver (version 1.3)
13:28:00,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Po
ol -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:28:01,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS0
11800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:28:01,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48)
JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:28:01,011 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBA
S013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:28:01,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS01
5400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:28:01,149 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011802: St
arting Naming Service
13:28:01,145 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread
 1-6) DÚmarrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http--127.0.0.1-8080
13:28:01,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011
940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
13:28:01,495 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service
thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:28:01,278 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013100:
Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
13:28:01,277 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC se
rvice thread 1-2) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
```

Does anybody can help me with that ? I have no clue on what's possibly worng. Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your trace, I can see you're running on Java 8.  While JBoss AS 7 *should* work on Java 8, it would appear that no testing was done to confirm this.  To verify, install the Java 7 JRE and attempt to start up JBoss with that.  Alternatively, you could jump straight to the next version, Wildfly.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/238195

https://community.jboss.org/message/872293

Comment: I tried to install Java 7, and it worked like a charm ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you are using standalone.conf.bat instead of standalone.bat. Did you try starting by executing standalone.bat as this is the executable to start a JBoss AS instance. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got the newest version of Wildfly which worked for me.

My Java 8 wasn't compatible with JBoss AS7 so I prefered to upgrade the JBoss version rather than downgrade the Java version.

Just make sure that your JBOSS_HOME variable now points to the new folder also.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue. This is the stack trace which i got from JBoss.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
15:09:25,305 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:09:26,409 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:09:26,507 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting

**Solution:**

When i change JAVA_HOME path from jdk 1.8 to jdk 1.7 it is working fine.